# Error running SURF demo code

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I was able to compile the code but when I run it I am receiving this error.

i'm using VS 2010 and opencv 248 in win 7.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Add some of your code.

Comment: i just use the recent version for windows code from http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/download_ac.html.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem. SURF developers said in order to use library we should use gcc compiler. I think our problem is not SURF rather how to use gcc with Visual studio